# Python advanced sorting in Lists

Tags: python

In following python list

```
a = ['BB', 'zz', 'CC', 'aa']
```

and if we apply `sorted(a, key=str.isupper)` to the list it gives the output as

```
['zz', 'aa', 'BB', 'CC']
```

Can anybody explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Could you clarify what has confused you? Is that *not* the order you expected? What output *were* you expecting, and on what basis?

Comment: I just wanted to know how it came i.e the logic behind it.

Comment: Well you *wrote* it, you have access to all of the documentation, what do you think?

Comment: Our professor showed us this sorting in class. but i was unable to understand that how it delivers this output

Comment: So **ask them**. Without a specific question, the answer could be, for example: Timsort; it’s a stable sort; that’s a Boolean not a string; or `False < True`. Again, **what output did you *expect* it would produce, and *why*?**

Comment: My query is resolved now!!. **Thanks a lot!!**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sort function sorts boolean list in an ascending order in this case.

`str.isuppper` is applied to each element.

```
a = ['BB', 'zz', 'CC', 'aa']  
a = [True, False, True, False]
```

`False` (internally 0) is smaller than `True` (internally 1).

For the same `False`s and `True`s, the order does not need to be changed.

So,

```
a = ['zz', 'aa', 'BB', 'CC']
```

Comment: Yes it solved my query...

Comment: @SHIVASRAINA Would you please accept this?

Comment: accepted... sorry for the delay

Comment: @SHIVASRAINA Thank you!